# Regular expression to get dimension in a filename

Tags: php, regex

I have strings:

```
1920x1080_photo_of_my_travel
photo_of_my_travel_1920x1080
photo_of_my_travel_1920x1080_version_1
1920X1080_photo_of_my_travel
photo_of_my_travel_1920X1080
photo_of_my_travel_1920X1080_version_1
```

How can I get 1920x1080 from these strings?

What I tried:

```
preg_match('#\\{FINDME\\}(.+)\\{/FINDME\\}#s',$out,$matches);
```

I think I'm a little bit lost...

Comment: Why are you matching `{FINDME}` tag?

Comment: `(?<![^\W_])\d+x\d+(?![^\W_])`

Comment: For these strings, `$dimension = '1920x1080';`. They're all 1920x1080. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to match digits `\d` one or more times `+` followed by `x` followed by digits `\d` one or more times `+`, case-insensitive `i`:

```
preg_match('#\d+x\d+#i', $out, $matches);
```

Or just match `x` or `X`:

```
\d+[xX]\d+
```